# Problems converting a NSDate to a string

Tags: nsdate

This extremely simple task was apparantly very hard...

```
NSDate *date;
date = [someMethod here];
//I've checked with debugger that the method returns an object of type NSDate. 
//The description of date at this point is: "2012-02-02 19:42:00 +0000"

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat;
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yy hh:mm"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
```

**dateString is just NIL**

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Edit: What i really want to achieve is simply:

```
NSString *receivedDate = @"2012-02-02T20:42:00+01:00";
NSString *fixedDate = [do some magic]
//value of fixedDate is now: "02-02-12 20:42"
```

Comment: Aren't you forgetting to alloc+init dateFormat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Anna said you need to allocate an instance of NSDateFormatter because all you get is a NULL ptr, which just ignores the messages setDateFormat and stringFromDate, leaving you with NULL.

But also your format is for hours is incorrect. Refer to [Date Formatter reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1)

This works for me:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[df setDateFormat:@@"dd-MM-yy HH:mm"];
NSString *dateString = [df stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: [sovled] It sort of works after i added alloc/init. But it parses the hour time wrong.
In: 2012-02-03 14:20:00 +0000
Out: 2012-02-03 02:20:00
Anyone know why it treats 14 as 2 in the night instead of day?
Edit: of course, I had hh instead of HH, works now!